# how to turn off the single sign on of two mvc application running on the same browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have 2 MVC applications deployed on the same server. If I run the two applications on the same browser(IE, chrome, firefox,...etc.) and logout out from the first application, the second application will logout automatically.

I want to allow the user to turn off from the first application and to continue working on the second application without signing in again and vice versa

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Are both the application in the same directory? We faced a similar problem which we got rid by applying special permissions on the folder(the directory where your app is hosted) and Created new instance of both apps.

Comment: what you mean by same directory? first application: wwwroot\LearningCenter and second application wwwroot\ContractManagement so i think, they aren't in the same directory right?

Comment: try changing the main directory as well.. as in completely different directory including the parent directory

Comment: i put LearningCenter under C and i didn't touch ContractManagement, it still when i login on one of the both and try to click any link in the other, it redirect to login page

Comment: They of course should laugh, as you should learn more details about authentication about ASP.NET just like how they learn their stacks. http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/ssoformsauth